# Get data from json form-data and store in database in django

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

My JSON file : (It's a file)

{ "user-id": 10009, "rating": 3, "movie_id": 9823 }

I need to get the each data separately.so I can store them in database. the JSON file is a form-data.

I tried:

```
    def post(self, request):

        data = request.FILES['json_file']
        # a = data.read().decode('utf-8')
        a = json.loads(data)
        x = a['user-id']
        print(x)

    return Response(x, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The above code is not working and giving me error:

```
the JSON object must be str, not 'InMemoryUploadedFile'
```

How can i get data from JSON file(form-data) and store it's content in database?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`data` is of the type `InMemoryUploadedFile`, so to convert it to a string you need to read it (as bytes) and convert it to a string:

```
 def post(self, request):

        data = request.data.get('json_file')
        a = json.loads(str(data.read()))
        x = a['user-id']
        print(x)

    return Response(x, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error which i'm getting @SteveK

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to call this function as well as a shortened stack trace of the error?

Comment: I have added postman screenshot @SteveK. and how can we retrieve "user-id" if it's a string, it should be dictionary.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a function that receives the request and passes it along to `post(request)` - what does that code look like?

Comment: The error almost looks like a JSON error - can you confirm the exact contents of the file you're testing with?

Comment: No, I don't have any other code other than the aboce post request where I want to fetch each item in json objec.

Comment: yaa the file content is : {"user-id": 10009,"rating": 3,"movie_id": 9823}

Comment: did you get the issue @SteveK

Comment: Is it because the value of `data` is actually "watchlist.json" and not JSON? What do you see when you `print(request)` in the function (before anything else)?

Comment: request is giving me request object when I print it. <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x000002092E512AC8>

Comment: What about `print(request.DATA)`?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'json_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: watchlist.json (application/json)>]}>

Comment: I've updated my answer - if you're still having issues, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284569/get-json-data-from-post-in-django-with-rest-framework